# How do I remove defined symbols from the .dynsym table in my executable?

Tags: elf

The .dynsym table in an ELF executable apparently has two purposes, imports and exports. I see that my executable has defined symbols (size>0) and undefined symbols (size=0, coming from library). Clearly the latter are needed, but I don't need or want to export any symbols from my executable. Who needs them? This adds ~3000 entries and ~350kB to my executable.

`strip` fails to remove them, it doesn't touch `.dynsym` apparently. So what tool can I use to remove those exports and shrink my executable?

I understand that I won't be able to call `dlopen` on my executable, that's acceptable.

[edit]
Turns out to be `-rdynamic`, which [CMake](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=5833) helpfully added.

Comment: Which defined symbols do you have in .dynsym in an executable? A simple hello world executable only has "__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5" and "__gmon_start__" on my machine. Function and globals defined in the program are not listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see that my executable has defined symbols (size>0) and undefined symbols (size=0, coming from library).

The size of the symbol has *nothing* to do with whether the symbol is defined or not.

> I don't need or want to export any symbols from my executable

Normally (in the absence of `--export-dynamic` or `-rdynamic` flags) the linker exports symbols from an executable *only* if the symbol is referenced by some shared library that you are linking, and the library will not work correctly if you manage to remove such symbol.

If you have 3000 exported symbols, it's likely that you have the `-rdynamic` flag. Some binaries will not work correctly without this flag (usually binaries that load plugins at runtime, but don't link against the plugins directly). Often there are better solutions for such binaries, such as explicitly exporting only the symbols that are required by the plugins.

Comment: Well, the undefined symbols are also marked as `UND` by `readelf`, and some of them are definitely provided by dynamically loaded Boost libraries, so _for my use case_ the size is relevant.